# Getting error code 500 while trying to make a POST request in Flutter

Tags: flutter, express, openai-api

Here's the backend server code:

```
require("dotenv").config();

const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const OpenAI = require("openai");

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_KEY,
});

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["https://xxxxx.vercel.app", "http://localhost:3000"],
  })
);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World!"));

// Get answer from GPT model
app.post("/generate", async (req, res) => {
  const { question } = req.body;
  try {
    const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      messages: [
        {
          role: "system",
          content:
            "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        },
        { role: "user", content: question },
      ],
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      temperature: 0.2
    });
    const answer = response.choices[0].message.content;
    res.status(200).json({ answer: answer });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error retrieving answer" });
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server up at PORT:${PORT}`));
```

Here's how I am trying to send a POST request in flutter:

```
final url = Uri.parse('https://xxxxx-express-api.onrender.com/generate');
final body = jsonEncode({'question': prompt});
final response = await http.post(url, body: body);
print(response.statusCode);
```

Here's the error in backend server console: `BadRequestError: 400 'content' is a required property - 'messages.1'`

Here's the error code in flutter: `500`

What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

So I figured out that the `prompt` I was passing wasn't just a `String`, but a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` so I rewrote the backend code like this:

```
    require("dotenv").config();
    
    const express = require("express");
    const cors = require("cors");
    const app = express();
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    const OpenAI = require("openai");
    
    const openai = new OpenAI({
      apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_KEY,
    });
    
    app.use(
      cors({
        origin: ["https://xxxxx.vercel.app", "http://localhost:3000"],
      })
    );
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    
    app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World!"));
    
    // Get answer from GPT model
    app.post("/generate", async (req, res) => {
      const { question } = req.body;
      try {
        const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
          messages: question,
          model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
          temperature: 0.2
        });
        const answer = response.choices[0].message.content;
        res.status(200).json({ answer: answer });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Error retrieving answer" });
      }
    });
    
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server up at PORT:${PORT}`));
```

Now, the log in backend server console is:

```
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM  BadRequestError: 400 'messages' is a required property
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      at APIError.generate (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/openai/error.js:43:20)
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      at OpenAI.makeStatusError (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/openai/core.js:248:33)
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      at OpenAI.makeRequest (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/openai/core.js:287:30)
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      at async /opt/render/project/src/index.js:23:22 {
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM    status: 400,
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM    headers: {
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400',
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      'cf-cache-status': 'DYNAMIC',
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      'cf-ray': 'xxx-SIN',
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      connection: 'keep-alive',
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      'content-length': '146',
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      'content-type': 'application/json',
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      date: 'Tue, 31 Oct 2023 07:57:06 GMT',
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      'openai-organization': 'user-xxx',
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      'openai-processing-ms': '4',
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      'openai-version': '2020-10-01',
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      server: 'cloudflare',
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains',
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      'x-ratelimit-limit-requests': '3500',
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      'x-ratelimit-limit-tokens': '90000',
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      'x-ratelimit-remaining-requests': '3499',
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      'x-ratelimit-remaining-tokens': '89983',
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      'x-ratelimit-reset-requests': '17ms',
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      'x-ratelimit-reset-tokens': '10ms',
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      'x-request-id': 'xxx'
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM    },
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM    error: {
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      message: "'messages' is a required property",
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      type: 'invalid_request_error',
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      param: null,
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM      code: null
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM    },
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM    code: null,
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM    param: null,
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM    type: 'invalid_request_error'
Oct 31 01:27:06 PM  }
```

I don't get it what's the problem with my request.

Comment: Are you sure, that the `question` property in your POST request is not empty or null? Where do you define `prompt`?

Comment: @Geshode please check the 'EDIT'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Needed some changes to be made.

Here's backend server code:

```
require("dotenv").config();

const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const OpenAI = require("openai");

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World!"));

// Get answer from GPT model
app.post("/generate", async (req, res) => {
  const question = req.body.question;
  try {
    const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      messages: question,
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      temperature: 0.2,
    });
    const answer = response.choices[0].message.content;
    res.status(200).json({ answer: answer });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error retrieving answer" });
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server up at PORT:${PORT}`));
```

Here's the flutter code:

```
final url = Uri.parse('https://xxxxx-express-api.onrender.com/generate');
final body = jsonEncode({'question': prompt});
final response = await http.post(url, headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: body);
```